# Get column index from table header in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to get the column index from a table header?

I have a table that I am applying a filter to and I then wish to set a bunch of parameters up from the filtered data using the column headers.

The formula I am testing in this case is:

```
=LET(setPrjFiltered, FILTER(StaffDetailsTbl,StaffDetailsTbl[Discipline]= "Programming"),
namesPrj, INDEX(setPrjFiltered,, StaffDetailsTbl[Employee]),
namesPrj)
```

This results in an error, whereas if I use the index in this form `INDEX(setPrjFiltered,, 1)`, it is fine. As this particular formula will hold a bunch of parameters set up in a similar way and the same function will be used a good number of times in the sheet I'd like it to use the table column to reference the index of the column - meaning I wont have to modify any indexes in the functions should the source data change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. The MATCH will look for the word "Employee" in the headers of the StaffDetailsTbl table and return it's position.

The third argument of INDEX is the column index, not the column itself. I think this is why your original formula returns an error.

```
=LET(setPrjFiltered, FILTER(StaffDetailsTbl,StaffDetailsTbl[Discipline]= "Programming"),
namesPrj, INDEX(setPrjFiltered,, MATCH("Employee", StaffDetailsTbl[#Headers], 0)),
namesPrj)
```

Comment: using MATCH("Employee",StaffDetailsTbl[#Headers]) gives the index 4 whereas the index for the employee column is 1, any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: @AutomationMonkey Sorry, forgot the 0 which specifies that only exact matches are valid. Try now, I edited the formula.